# Can this code be written without explicit recursion? [Project Euler #31 spoiler]

Tags: haskell

This function is at the heart of a solution to a Project Euler problem:

```
numWays tot (d:ds) = sum $ map (flip numWays ds . (tot -)) [0, d .. tot]
numWays tot []
    | tot == 0     = 1
    | otherwise    = 0
```

I want to believe it can be rewritten without explicit recursion, but the fact that the recursion is under a map has stymied my efforts to find it.

Comment: May I ask why you want to write it without explicit recursion? Explicit recursion makes it far easier to add the optimisation to treat the case of a one-element list specially. If you pass your list of denominations in descending order (so that the last denomination is 1), that is a particularly fruitful optimisation (try it with a total of 400 or 800 to see what I'm talking about). Of course, a better algorithm will blow that out of the water still.

Comment: Purely to expand my understanding of fold-as-list-processor.  I have a naive understanding that the given algo matches the 'fold pattern' and I wanted to see what it might look like if converted to a fold.

Comment: Ah, that's a good reason of course. I kind of feared you had heard that explicit recursion was bad once too often and started believing it. (Not that explicit recursion is generally better either, of course, it depends.) Since this algorithm branches, it doesn't really match the fold pattern too well (as illustrated by the fact that dave's rewrite has the fold innermost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Data.List (genericLength)

numWays' tot = genericLength . filter (== 0) . foldl snoc [tot] where
        snoc tots d = concatMap f tots where
                f tot = map (tot -) [0, d .. tot]
```

I use `genericLength` instead of `length` so that my `numWays'` has the same type as your `numWays` (`(Num c, Num b, Enum b) => b -> [b] -> c`).

The idea here is that instead of counting one (for zero residual total) or zero (for a non-zero residual total) and summing them, we decompose the function into a recursive function that generates a list of residuals, and then (non-recursively) count how many zeroes there are in that list.

The point of doing this is that it leaves us with a recursive function we can more easily remove the recursion from.